# Azure release pipeline task. There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a Azure release pipeline with one of the step is to copy the file (let say "xyz.txt") from working directory to Azure storage container as a Blob file. It was working fine and doing its job as expected till yesterday.

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@3
  displayName: 'Copy file to BLOB'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/FilePath'
    azureSubscription: 'ABCSubscription'
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: ABCstorage
    ContainerName: abcContainerName
```

Now I have made some changes to the file ("xyz.txt") and whenever I am creating release from release pipeline,  I am seeing the error `"The remote server returned an error: (412) There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request..`. This is causing release pipeline to fail. What is the solution for this?

Do i have to login to portal and click `"Break lease"` manually. Is there a way to do this (`"Break lease"`) through pipeline only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below work arounds to **break lease** :

**Solution 1:** In Azure Devops it will be like below :

```
steps: 

  - task: AzureCLI@2 

    displayName: "Break lease on terraform state" 

    name: BreakLease 

    inputs: 

      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.ServiceConnectionName }} 

      scriptType: "pscore" 

      scriptLocation: "inlineScript" 

      inlineScript: "az storage blob lease break --container-name 'test' --blob-name '${{ parameters.File }}' --account-name '${{ parameters.StorageAccountName }}'"
```

**Solution 2:** You can break the lease through [azure storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/):

if you want Break Lease on Container

**STEP 1:**  go to **storage account** --> select the **container** right click on container Select the **Break lease** .

[image]

Same for the **blob** in **container** .

[image]

**Solution 3 :** Use Azure CLI Commands to break the lease

```
az storage blob lease break --blob-name   --container-name [--account-key]  [--account-name] 
[--auth-mode {key, login}] [--connection-string] [--if-match] [--if-modified-since] 
[--if-none-match] [--if-unmodified-since] [--lease-break-period] [--sas-token] 
[--subscription] [--tags-condition] [--timeout]
```

For more details refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/lease?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_lease_break

Comment: Thanks @ShrutiJoshi! trying this.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Solution 1 worked perfectly for me. I have accepted this answer.